# How to rotate from portrait to landscape in Xcode Assistant Editor Preview Mode

Tags: xcode

I am using the Preview Mode in Interface builder in Xcode 10 and cannot see how to rotate from portrait to landscape.
In previous versions you just moved the mouse pointer over the preview outline and got a rotation button. This isn't happening for me.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is impossible to see in dark mode, but click right where the arrow is and you will be good to go.

[image]

Comment: No. It's the window to the right of that when you click Assistant Editor/Preview. I've edited my question to show.

Comment: I have your answer. It is annoying because its hard to see hold up and I will update my answer

Comment: There you go and yes, it should be white or something, not black. Really annoying. @Steve Harris

Comment: That's the one I keep clicking on but nothing is happening